# Angular-cli only register component

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular-cli, angular7

I have an angular project as base project and i have some dynamic generated html, scss and ts code  that i want to "merge" or introduce into that base project. I mean, i have the component code already but i want to import the component into the project module.

How can i import the component? (I have the name of the component to do that).

specifically, ng g c name usually runs:

```
CREATE src/app/name/name.component.scss (0 bytes)
CREATE src/app/name/name.component.html (23 bytes)
CREATE src/app/name/name.component.spec.ts (614 bytes)
CREATE src/app/name/name.component.ts (262 bytes)
UPDATE src/app/app.module.ts (652 bytes)
```

but i want to run only the UPDATE step.

(the code doesn't reside on angular project yet but after the module import, that  will be just after git push into the project)

How can i do that?

Comment: Move/paste your code in to the existing project, and manually update the module.

Comment: Well, it's just the behavior i want to avoid with some rare command or something. Im working in a project generator so the idea is not involve user on do that kind of things manually.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already generated component with the specific module , it should reside within the module already.

There is no specific command just to add the component to the module, what you could opt for is manually adding it.

or remove it completely, generate component wiht ng g c command and add the code manually.

Comment: Actually the code doesn't reside on angular project yet but i will after the module import, that is only a git push command.